# multiple concatenation the alphabet if it is not available in the variable 1 and available in variable 2

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two variables in the xslt for example named var1 and var2.

> Var1 = A,B,C,D,F G,H Var2 = L,M,F,C,D,K

I want to check that if any alphabet is not present in Var1 and present in Var2 ,append this alphabet after the Var1.
Means eventually i want below value stored in to var1

> A,B,C,D,F,G,H,L,M,K

I am thinking something like below which is not working -

```
<xsl:variable name="Var1">
  <xsl:if test="not(contains($va1,'L'))">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($va1, 'L')"/>
   </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(contains($va1,'M'))">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($va1, 'M')"/>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:variable>
```

NOTE - I am  XSLT beginner and above code is just  something in my head  only and not tried so do not go with down vote please.

Comment: Variables in XSLT are not variable - you can't change the value of a variable after it has been created.  This sounds like an A-B problem to me, you need to take a step back and ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve, rather than the specific step you've got stuck on.  XSLT works quite differently from traditional procedural programming languages and you often have to approach the whole problem in a different way entirely.

Comment: I second Robert's thoughts but it looks rather like the union than the difference of the two letter sets.

Comment: It would help knowing how these variables get populated and what do you expect to do with the result. In XSLT 1.0, a comma-separated list is **not** a convenient format to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to some extent, but `,` are not preserved for `$var2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="var1">
    <xsl:text>A,B,C,D,F,G,H</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="var2">
    <xsl:text>L,M,F,C,D,K</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="merged" select="concat(concat($var1, ','), translate($var2, $var1, ''))"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$merged"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
A,B,C,D,F,G,H,LMK
```

Note that with XSLT 1.0, it's only possible for single characters like in your example (`translate` does not replace substrings!).

If you don't need the merged characters in a variable, you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="sep" select="','"/>

  <xsl:variable name="var1">
    <xsl:text>A,B,C,D,F,G,H</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="var2">
    <xsl:text>L,M,F,C,D,K</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="not-contained">
      <xsl:with-param name="string1" select="$var1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="string2" select="$var2"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="not-contained">
    <xsl:param name="string1"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="string2"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="$sep"/>
    <xsl:param name="match"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$match"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string2, $sep)">
        <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($string2, $sep)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="no-match" select="not(contains($string1, $before))"/>
        <xsl:if test="$no-match">
          <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="not-contained">
          <xsl:with-param name="string1" select="$string1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="string2" select="substring-after($string2, $sep)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="match">
            <xsl:if test="$no-match">
              <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($string1, $string2))">
          <xsl:value-of select="$string2"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
A,B,C,D,F,G,H,L,M,K
```

If every letter was a text node in a source document, `<xsl:key>` could be used to group them together and thus eliminate duplicates.